# How to create Option bar

Tags: android, layout, widget

I want to create a bar with different widgets like this ..

[image]

Instead of two Chinese box i want to show a spinner and a edittext area.And at the bottom of this bar there is a listview.

any One know how to create this?

What I tried...

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
     android:orientation="vertical"   
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
 <Spinner
      android:id="@+id/spinner" 
      android:layout_width="0dip"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:prompt="@string/country"  
      android:layout_weight="1"/>
 <EditText 
   android:id="@+id/edittextserach"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Search here"
   android:layout_weight="1"

   />
 <ImageButton 
  android:id="@+id/imagesearch"
  android:src="@drawable/search_icon"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:layout_weight="0"
  android:layout_marginBottom="8dip"
  android:paddingBottom="12dip"/>
 </LinearLayout>

<ListView 
  android:id="@+id/android:list"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />"
 </LinearLayout>
```

I know my layout is strange but i can't find any tutorial on this. I am new to this type of layouts.

[image]

Comment: what is the issue you getting?

Comment: when i entered a long text in edittext spinner and search button go disappear.

Comment: which android version are you running this? Is it emulator or device?

Comment: 2.1 emulator in landscape mode.

Comment: but in graphics layout mode in eclipse there is no problem.

Comment: i cant see any problem in my emulator 2.3.3. I too have a bigger icon as you have in your screen shot

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5613/discussion-between-john-smith-and-havexz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try restricting your EditText like this

Choose maxWidth which make sense. And enabling scrollHorizontally will make sure it says in single line even after typing long text.

```
android:maxWidth="100dip"   
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
```

Complete layout for EditText:

```
 <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittextserach"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxWidth="100dip"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:text="Search here" />
```

Comment: it works but i don't know why spinner and search bar and image button are not linear check the edited question.

Comment: i tried layout_marginbottom="10dip" on spinner but it does not change.

Answer (score 0):

Use [android:maxWidth](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3amaxWidth) Attribute

```
<EditText 
   android:id="@+id/edittextserach"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Search here"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:maxWidth="20sp"
 />
```